# Can I pass a type as parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, types

I'd like to pass (any type, not only PHP's primitives) Type as a function parameter. More like a C++'s template. Is it possible in PHP? imaginary code:

```
function foo(T a)
{
   $output = new T();
   //do something.
}
```

I tried pass the type name as string and then use `settype()` to the the variable to that type but `settype()` work only with PHP's primitives types. My goal is actually pass a class type as parameter.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: not sure if I understood, how can I pass a type as parameter using it? so far I can understand, it's useful as type checking because it does force a function to work only with a particular object type

Comment: Not sure I understand still, but `get_class($a);` should result in `T`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to instantiate something like the above, how about passing the classname as a string and then instantiating it!

```
function foo($obj_string)
{
    $object = new $obj_string();
    //do stuff with $object
}
```

Comment: I had no idea it's possible in PHP. I was about to use  `$object = eval("new ".$typeName."();");` ! thanks!

Comment: Yea, PHP is scary weird. If you don't mind marking mine as the answer, I'd appreciate the points!

Comment: Does PHP variables are just like C's macros? LOL I'm waiting to be able to accept your answer. About 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you already accepted an answer, but from the original post, it shows passing an object variable in the function. For those viewing this that need to do it that way, instead of being able to pass the name of the class as a string, you can do it this way:

```
class Blah
{
    public $x = 123;
}


function Foo($b) {
    $class = get_class($b);
    $object = new $class();
    var_dump($object);
}

$aa = new Blah();
Foo($aa);
```

Comment: Your now constructing a new Blah **twice**? What's the use of this? What does this solve?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit old but I'll leave an answer anyway just in case it's helpful.

If I am going to pass an object as a parameter to another object, it's going to be after I have instantiated the object argument and adjusted the properties to my needs. The following is an example of how I would go about it. I'm using this on PHP 7.4.x and haven't tested on PHP 8.x yet.

Class Blah is the object that will be passed to an instance of Class Bleep after the property $x within the Class Blah object has been changed from 123 to 456.

```
<?php

class Blah {
  public $x = 123;
  function __construct() {}

  function set_x($x) {
    $this->x = $x;
  }

  function get_x() {
    return $this->x;
  }

}

class Bleep {

  public $object;

  function __construct($object) {
    $this->object = $object;
  }

  function get_object_x() {
    return $this->object->get_x();
  }

}

// Example in use.
$obj_bla = new Blah();
print '<p>On instantiation of <u>$obj_bla</u> as a <strong>Blah</strong> object, $x = '.$obj_bla->get_x().'</p>';
$obj_bla->set_x(456);
print '<p>After using the method <i>set_x()</i> on <u>$obj_bla</u>, $x = '.$obj_bla->get_x().'</p>';

$obj_bleep = new Bleep($obj_bla);
print '<p>Instantiate <u>$obj_bleep</u> as a new <strong>Bleep</strong> object and pass it the instance of <u>$obj_bla</u> then use the <i>get_object_x()</i> method on <u>$obj_bleep</u> to get the value of x from the object that was passed = '.$obj_bleep->get_object_x().'</p>'

?>
```